# '80s or '90s movie with a one-eyed monster and a couple of children in a castle

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie I saw when I was a kid in the '90s, in Finland. I suspect the movie was made in the '80s. I'm not sure if it was European or from the US.

The movie had a medieval castle or a similar building, a couple of children and a monster. The monster was about the size of a human, with a big head but no torso, a single eye and mouth, two big legs, and kind of fins for arms. The monster is what I remember best. I also have a recollection one of the kids being turned into a monster, but I could be wrong.

It was a live action movie, and I think the monster was played by an actor in a janky suit.

Comment: So was the monster similar in appearance to [Mike Wazowski](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/Mike_Wazowski) from _Monsters, Inc._...?

Comment: @LogicDictates Well kind of! I think it was brown, and had coarse skin, and more of a snout. And short fin-like hands instead of arms.